# how to add bottom spacing of a div tag with css

Tags: html, css

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/e7tn8grv/) is my example I want to show you. I have a div tag with the id of `form-bubble` in the middle of the container. I added a `margin:20px auto;` to the `form-bubble`. But the form-bubble is not getting any space at the bottom. I don't know how to create space at the bottom. I'm pretty sure that I can create a `padding-bottom` for the `container`, but I want to see if there is another way to do it.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <h1 id="project-title">Add Properties</h1>
    <div id="form-bubble">
     <input type="text" placeholder="this is text">
      <!--</form>-->
      </div>
  </div><!-- container -->
```

CSS

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:grey;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

#container{
margin:auto;

max-width:1170px;
min-width:960px;
background:white;
}

#project-title{
text-align:center;
margin-top:0;
padding-top:20px;

}

#form-bubble{
background:#3399ff;
padding:5px;
width:189px;
display:block;
border-radius: 3px;
margin:20px auto;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you may activate the [Block Formating Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) to hold [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) *(usually used to deal with float)* , here via `overflow:hidden;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-width: 960px;
  background: white;
  overflow:hidden;/* BFC */
}

#project-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#form-bubble {
  background: #3399ff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 189px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="project-title">Add Properties</h1>
  <div id="form-bubble">
    <input type="text" placeholder="this is text">
    <!--</form>-->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e7tn8grv/2/

---

## Most common way to hold margins inside parent container.

to keep margin inside the container (see again collapsing margins) you may also add a padding or a border (snippets below, third is defaut behavior you can notice setting different background-colors to html & body:

---

padding cure

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-width: 960px;
  background: white;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}

#project-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#form-bubble {
  background: #3399ff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 189px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="project-title">Add Properties</h1>
  <div id="form-bubble">
    <input type="text" placeholder="this is text">
    <!--</form>-->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

---

margin cure

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-width: 960px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}

#project-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#form-bubble {
  background: #3399ff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 189px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="project-title">Add Properties</h1>
  <div id="form-bubble">
    <input type="text" placeholder="this is text">
    <!--</form>-->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

defaut behavior you can noticed with different background-colors *(still border applied to body to hold child margins)*

```css
html {
  background:yellow;
  }
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px;/* hold collapsing margins here */
  background: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-width: 960px;
  background: white;
}

#project-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#form-bubble {
  background: #3399ff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 189px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="project-title">Add Properties</h1>
  <div id="form-bubble">
    <input type="text" placeholder="this is text">
    <!--</form>-->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `padding-bottom: 20px;` to `#container`. Then you can remove the margin from the `#form-bubble`.
Why? Because there is nothing below `#form-bubble` to "move". What you see is the grey background of your body. So you have to expand the height of your container.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-width: 960px;
  background: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#project-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#form-bubble {
  background: #3399ff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 189px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="project-title">Add Properties</h1>
  <div id="form-bubble">
    <input type="text" placeholder="this is text">
    <!--</form>-->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```html
  body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:grey;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

#container{
margin:auto;

max-width:1170px;
min-width:960px;
background:white;
}

#project-title{
text-align:center;
margin-top:0;
padding-top:20px;

}

#form-bubble{
background:#3399ff;
padding:5px;
width:189px;
display:block;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-bottom:20px;

}
```